# Mysql - Query with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query multiple ids from `table1`, and if the `id` from `table1` exists in `table2` then get the row of it, and also if the `id` from `table2` exists in `table3` do the same thing.

I'm expecting the following result;

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       table1         |       table2       |      table3       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id   specific_column   | id   table1_id     | id    table2_id
1    4457                1    1               1     1
8    8477                6    8               2     6
25   8339                3    25              54    3   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried using `IN` in my query but I only get single row

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 

WHERE (table1.specific_column)

IN (4457, 8477, 8339)

AND table2.table1_id = table1.id

AND table3.table2_id = table2.ID
```

The current result is;

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       table1         |       table2       |      table3       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id   specific_column   | id   table1_id     | id    table2_id
1    4457                1    1               1     1
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to rewrite this using clearer `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.table2_id = t2.id
  WHERE t1.specific_column IN (4457, 8477, 8339)
```

The problem with your existing query is that it was using an `INNER JOIN` which meant that only rows with matching results across all three tables were showing.

Using a `LEFT JOIN` will return all results from the left-hand tables and matching results from the right-hand tables (hence showing `NULL` values where the `JOIN` fails).